# Can we give used clothing as zakat instead of money?

Tags: zakat

Sometimes we pass difficult times about money.. I'm not eligible to give zakat yet. but would like to know if we can give used clothing as zakat instead of money?

Zazakallah Khair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assalamualaikum,

there is no zakat on the things of your ordinary usage. zakat is only on your excess wealth. if your excess wealth crosses limit of the Niasb of zakat, only then you are eligible for giving zakat, otherwise if you are not eligible for paying zakat,then no need to give anything at all. if you dont give anything,you are not doing a sin atleast.

But besides zakat, you can just give sadaka (which is not obligaory , but highly recommended to give to needy and poor)

and Allah knows the best

Comment: Walaikumassalam..
Thanks for your information. yes.. I know that I can give things as sadqah. But I wanted to know this for future purpose and also for my family and others. So, I wanted to know that if its permissible to give used clothing as zakat?

Zazakallah Khair.. and Allah knows the best

Comment: What about large scale clothing donations, such as excess from a clothing business?